# Class 'PHPMailer' not found after installing PHPmailer with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

Attempting to user PHPmailer following installation with Composer causes this error.

This is the first time I've tried Composer. I believe I have successfully installed both Composer and PHPmailer following the instructions on the relevant sites. In the root directory of my website I now have directories .composer , .subversion, and vendor. The last of these has a subdirectory phpmailer/phpmailer which contains composer.json . The webroot is a subdirectory off the siteroot.

What am I doing wrong? And now can I fault-find the error?

EDIT

This is sample code I'm using:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . '/config/setup.php');
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/php/inc/errorhandler.php');
require_once dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  //LINE 7//
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$msgrubric = 'This message is from the contact form on the website.' . "\n\n";

try
{
  $mail->IsSendmail();
  $mail->AddAddress(CONTACTFORM_ADDR);
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->AddReplyTo($fieldData['email']);
  $mail->Subject = $fieldData['subject'];
  $mail->SetFrom($fieldData['email'], $fieldData['name']);  
  $mail->Body = $msgrubric . $fieldData['message'];
  $mail->Send();
}
catch (phpmailerException $e)
{
  echo ("<h1>Send us email</h1>");
  echo('<p>We regret that an error prevented submission of your message. ' .
    'The fault has been logged and will be corrected as soon as possible. ' .
    'Please try again later. ' . "\n");
  trigger_error('Unable to send email in contact form', E_USER_WARNING);
  return false;

}
return true;
```

This gives the error message `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /homepages/15/d00000000/htdocs/tvcdev/php/main/testmail.php:7`

Comment: Try to put this in your code: `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;`

Comment: Can you share the relevant portions of your script file please?...

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: on top of controller, import that class by `use \PHPMailer`

Comment: That phpmail/phpmailer subdir - does it contain other files too? It would help if you ;osted your code and details of your file structure.

Comment: @Script47: I've just tried that in site root and get `command not found` response.

Comment: @magnol Odd. How about [`composer dump`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#command-line-interface-commands)?

Comment: @Script47: same response.

Comment: Are you sure you have composer installed correctly?

Comment: @Script47: I reinstalled Composer and PHPmailer and realised that 1and1 requires me to use `/usr/bin/php5.5-cli composer.phar`, not just composer. (Can't use Sudo.) Using that CLI, both packages announce themselves as successfuly installed.  Now using `dump-autoload` gives the message `Generated autoload containing 0 classes.` Where do I go from here?

Comment: @magnol try executing your code again.

Comment: @Script47: Done. See sample code and response in my edit above.

Comment: Take a look at @Gudgip comment above.